# PHP/SQL connection script

Tags: php, mysql, database

someone please help me to set mysql database connection variable on below php scripts but I couldn't fixed it.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT r.itemID, r2.ratingValue - r.ratingValue 
            as rating_difference
            FROM rating r, rating r2
            WHERE r.userID=$userID AND 
                    r2.itemID=$itemID AND 
                    r2.userID=$userID;";
$db_result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($db_result);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($db_result)) {
    $other_itemID = $row["itemID"];
    $rating_difference = $row["rating_difference"];
    if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT itemID1 
    FROM dev WHERE itemID1=$itemID AND itemID2=$other_itemID",
    $connection)) > 0)  {
        $sql = "UPDATE dev SET count=count+1, 
    sum=sum+$rating_difference WHERE itemID1=$itemID 
    AND itemID2=$other_itemID";
        mysql_query($sql, $connection);
        if ($itemID != $other_itemID) {
            $sql = "UPDATE dev SET count=count+1, 
        sum=sum-$rating_difference 
        WHERE (itemID1=$other_itemID AND itemID2=$itemID)";
            mysql_query($sql, $connection);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code before posting your question. This is unreadable.

Comment: We can't help you to fix it if you don't tell us what's wrong with it.

Comment: Here is code http://lemire.me/fr/documents/publications/webpaper.txt

Comment: @user3545724: `"I want to add mysql connection variables above."` - Then add them.  What exactly are you stuck on?  Are you just looking for a tutorial on how to use MySQL in PHP?  (Note: You probably want to take this opportunity to use something more modern than `mysql_*` functions, as those are easily prone to vulnerabilities.)

Comment: And once again: stop `using` msql statements, they are depricated. Use `mysqli` instead

Comment: Where do you connect to the database? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You didn't connect to any database use some thing like this

```
$link = mysql_connect('dbhost', 'dbusername', 'dbpassword');
$connection = mysql_select_db('tablename', $link);
```

Comment: Exactly. I want to add it. Where to add this?

Comment: Add top to your php file where your queries are created or create new php file named "connection.php" and include in the file where you want to use db queries

Comment: Did you done Is It working..